# What is the diffenence between ' specially' and ' especially'?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference, confusable

Can anyone tell the the difference between these two words, and in which condition should  they be used?

Comment: Hi Lucas - welcome to ELL! If you have looked up these words in a dictionary, please tell us the definitions you've found. It will help us explain it better if we understand what you already know and what is especially confusing. This post on meta has some advice for adding detail to your questions: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161

Comment: *I specially like materials treated specially to be water repellent, especially nanotech ones, especially because I have a few nano T-shirts specially designed by a brand specialized in sportswear my friend bought especially for me last year!*

Comment: Especially may be used when u usually want to emphasize heavily..

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything better than this:

[Straight from the MW Dictionary:](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/what-s-the-difference-between-specially-and-especially)

The meanings and usage of these two similar-sounding words overlap quite a bit, so it can be hard to figure out which one to use when. But here are some simple rules:

1) Use especially to mean “very” or “extremely,” as in these examples:

> There is nothing especially radical about that idea. 
>       The food was not especially good.

2) Use especially when something stands out from all the others, and you want the meaning of “particularly,” as in these examples:

> She can't be sure she will win, especially at this early stage of the
>      campaign.  
> The appetizers and especially the soup were delicious.

3) When you want to convey the meaning “for a special purpose,” or “specifically,” you can use either especially or specially. They are both correct.

> The speech was written especially/specially for the occasion.

4) When you want to convey the meaning “in a special manner”, as in this example below, use specially. In this context, especially would sound odd or wrong to most native speakers.

> I don't want to be treated specially.
>     <del>I don't want to be treated especially.</del>

Comment: I think that page is generally okay. However, note that the "simple rule" #1 "Use especially to mean “very” or “extremely”" overlaps with the definition given to *specially* by the dictionary itself: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/specially: "2. to a special or unusual degree : particularly or especially".

Answer (score -2):

Simply put, use "specially" if referring to something special, "especially" if it's specific or particular.